# Exam Grading Program in C

Tags: c, macros, struct, io, header

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out where and how to start this program. It is an assignment for school, but I **do not** want someone to do it for me. I just want help starting it and getting a foundation built so I can finish it myself.

The assignment is this:

A professor has written a 20 question True/False exam and gave it to all the students of the class. You
have been asked to write a program that grades this exam. However, to preserve space, the answers to
each submission are stored in a 20-bit binary number (represented as a decimal). For example, if the
stored number is 729494, the binary equivalent is 10110010000110010110. This means the answers
are TFTTFFTFFFFTTFFTFTTF. Each correct answer is worth 1 point, and each incorrect answer is
worth 0 points. Assume that each student completed the exam (i.e., no omitted answers).

Your program will input a list of student names and answers(for example: "Edwin Larson 568983"), and the program will output the score and
letter grade for each person(for example: "Edwin Larson 65% D"). Assume that each name (both first and last) cannot exceed 50 characters.
In order to make this work, your program **must** have the following features.

**File Input/Output**

Instead of having the user directly enter the input, all input will come from a text file. The first value
read will be the solution to the exam. All other lines will contain a student’s first name, last name, and
the number representing his/her answers to the exam. The user should be asked to enter the of the file.
If the file cannot be found, the user should keep entering the name of the file until a valid input file is
entered. A sample input file is provided.
Output should also be done with files. The results of the program should be written to a file. To make
the project simpler, you may write one score at a time instead of reading the entire input file and then
writing to the output file. The user should be asked to enter the name of the file. Note that the file does
not have to exist. If it’s not there, C will create the file automatically. The output should be the student’s
first and last names, the score (as a percent), and the letter grade.

**Structs and Types**

Since the exam answers are stored in a 20-bit integer, we need to store the answers in a 20-bit integer.
To do this, we will use a bit field. To make things simple, we’ll organize this in a struct. At a minimum,
the struct should contain the student’s first name, last name, and the number storing the answers (with
20 bits). Define this struct as a new data type called Student.

**Macros**

Once we compute the score, we need to determine the letter grade. To accomplish this, we will define
the following macros:
• IS_A - Check if the score is at least 90.
• IS_B - Check if the score is between 80 and 89.
• IS_C - Check if the score is between 70 and 79.
• IS_D - Check if the score is between 60 and 69.
If none of these macros return true, then the student gets an F on the exam.

**Header File**

The struct and the macros should be placed in a separate header file. The main C program will need to
include this header file.

```
#ifndef Header_H
#define Header_H

#define IS_A(x) ((x) >= (90))
#define IS_B(x) ((x) >= (80) && (x) <= (89))
#define IS_C(x) ((x) >= (70) && (x) <= (79))
#define IS_D(x) ((x) >= (60) && (x) <= (69))
#define IS_F(x) ((x) <= (59))

typedef struct
{
    char first[25];
    char last[25];
    unsigned int grade;

}Student;

#endif
```

I'm now getting an error stating my header file cannot be included because it cannot be found. I have made sure they're both in the same folder/directory.

Comment: Well, there's so much to do, I really don't know where to start or what to try. I'm overwhelmed. I tried reading the names and numbers from the files into arrays, but there were issues with memory or something because the arrays printed back nothing even close to what was read.

Comment: You need to understand [how to read nth bit, xor operation](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/low-level-bit-hacks-you-absolutely-must-know/), and [macros to check range](http://www.java2s.com/Code/C/Macro-Preprocessor/UseMacrotochecktheintrange.htm). With good understanding of this you should be able to write your code for 1 student easily. For more number of students, google for IO redirection, or FILE IO in C.

Comment: *"I tried reading the names and numbers from the files into arrays"* That's a good start, but you should only have one array, an array of structs (using the new data type called Student).  So add to the question your definition of the Student struct, the code that declares the array of structs, and the code that parses the input file and populates the array of structs.

Comment: The macros need to use `>=` and `<=`. For example `IS_B` is only true for `x` from `81` to `88` (should be 80 to 89). The struct looks OK, except that the `25` should be `51` (assuming that I've read the question correctly, and allowing for 50 characters plus a NUL terminator). Next step is to add the code that populates the structs.

Answer (score 0):

start by writing the macros and the main loop that reads the file.

then figure out how to find how many they got right.

remember failure is always an option.

Answer (score 0):

When reading the file its important you count the number of lines to determine how many took the test. Now you can start read, manipulate and write the result in a file.

My aproach would be. getNrOfParticipants -> and for each participant read data, manipulate and write the result. -> close outputfile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to assist you with converting a decimal to binary.  I quickly wrote it and tested it in eclipse.  I would create a function that returns a string so that you can call it from your main.  I

```
#include<stdio.h>

void binary(int dec)
{
    int a[20];
    int i=0;
    while(dec > 0)
    {
        a[i]=dec%2;
        i++;
        dec=dec/2;
    }
    int j = i;
    for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
        printf("%d",a[j]);
}

int main()
{
    int grade;
    printf("Enter a number:");

    scanf("%d",&grade);

    printf("Binary number of %d is ", grade);
    binary(grade);
}
```